Installation of electron-winstaller is so slow
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/2] ⠠ electron-winstaller
[2/2] ⠠ electron


When I install the dependency, it always gets stuck in step shown above.
Here is my package.json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "name": "electron-x",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron/fuses": "^1.8.0",
    "electron": "^31.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.1"
  }
}


I want to know why it is stuck and how to fix it.
Can somebody help?
